# Zero on non-inverting input for non-inverting amplifier gives output different than zero

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, analog, datasheet, output

I have downloaded spice models for LM358 and LM318 from TI website.
Can somebody please explain me the difference between outputs on both amplifiers.
I know that there should be some input offset voltage that is amplified, but the interesting part is that the output voltage does not depend on the closed loop gain formed by R3 and R4 and R5 and R6 for the other amplifier.
I cannot figure out why the outputs for the amplifiers are different. It is probably written somewhere in the datasheet, but I do not know where. Maybe some of the parameters in the datasheet can point out why this is happening. Schematic and DC operating point is showed in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum supply voltage for an LM318 is 10 volts - you have it powered at 5 volts. The LM358 will work quite happily down to 3 volts but you have other errors....

You are expecting the LM318 to operate with its inputs at the most negative rail i.e. 0 volts - inputs cannot get closer than 3.5 volts to either rail or it won't work: -

[image]

The spec inside the red box is for a +/-15 volt supply and inputs can be within +/-11.5 volts - that's no closer than 3.5 volts to either rail.

Notice also the output voltage spec - it tells you that the output isn't guaranteed to get to within 3 volts of either power rail.

Do things like this get better at lower supply voltage? NO

Comment: Good job. You beat out Null by 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

The [LM318 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm318-n.pdf) says that the device requires a minimum of a +/-5V dual supply:

[image: LM318]

You've only provided 5V.

You're also violating the common mode input voltage range for the LM318 by grounding the non-inverting input and using ground as the VSS rail. The input must be within +/-11.5V for a +/-15V supply.

[image: LM318 again]

Also, the output can only swing to within 3V of the rails.

The [LM358 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf) says it can be powered by a minimum of a 3V single supply, so it works.